# Bash - How to count C source file functions calls

Tags: bash, shell

I want to find for each function defined in a C source file how many times it's called and on which line.
Should I search for patterns which look like function definitions in C and then count how many times that function name occurs. If so, how can I do it? regular expressions?
Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -r $1 ]; then
       #??????
else    
        echo The file \"$1\" does NOT exist
fi
```

The final result is: (please report any bugs)

```
 10 if [ -r $1 ]; then
 11         functs=`grep -n -e "\(void\|double\|char\|int\) \w*(.*)"  $1 | sed 's/^.*\(void\|double\|int\) \(\w*\)(.*$/\2/g'`
 12         for f in $functs;do
 13                 echo -n  $f\(\) is called:
 14                 grep -n $f $1 > temp.txt
 15                 echo -n `grep -c -v -e "\(void\|double\|int\) $f(.*)" -e"//" temp.txt`
 16                 echo " times"
 17                 echo -n on lines:
 18                 echo -n `grep  -v -e "\(void\|double\|int\) $f(.*)" -e"//" temp.txt | sed -n 's/^\([0-9]*\)[:].*/\1/p'`
 19                 echo
 20                 echo
 21         done    
 22 else    
 23         echo The file \"$1\" does not exist
 24 fi
```

Comment: *... how many times it's called ...* – functions inside loop bodies may be called many time – but I guess you want just the syntactic count (appearances of a function name in the source file)...

Comment: Yeah, the syntactic count I'm looking for, Sorry for ambiguity

Comment: Here's an ANSI C grammer: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html for [yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc)

Comment: wouldn't you rather use a real static code analysis tool to do this?

Comment: You can't (or at least shouldn't, and probably still can't despite all the extensions that make this possible in theory) parse a nontrivial programming language with regular expression. And I hope you've made up your mind on wether macros should be expanded or not - and are aware of the problems with either approach.

Comment: well I have to use shell scripting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might sort of work. The first bit finds function definitions like

```
<datatype> <name>(<stuff>)
```

and pulls out the `<name>`. Then grep for that string. There are loads of situations where this won't work, but it might be a good place to start if you're trying to make a simple shell script that works on some programs.

```
functions=`grep -e "\(void\|double\|int\) \w*(.*)$" -f input.c | sed 's/^.*\(void\|double\|int\) \(\w*\)(.*$/\2/g'`
for func in $functions
do
  echo "Counting references for $func:"
  grep "$func" -f input.c | wc -l
done
```

Comment: But with this kind of grep you get only the definition of the function, not every time it is used. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: before the "for" statement it's dead, any idea why?

Comment: might need to be `for func in $functions`. You could try running the grep from the first line on its own, that should print out all the function names. @dash1e - the first line finds the definitions, the for loop should count the number of reference to each function.

Comment: The grep is not working; I'm not very sure what this thing does  `\w*(.*)$" -f input.c`

Comment: `-f input.c` is the name of the input file (input.c might need to be $1 in your example). `\w*(.*)$` will match any number of characters \w*, then brackets ( with anything .* in between them, then the end of the line $ (in this case, it should match things like myFunction(int a, int b) )

Comment: no, escaped brackets are for capturing, like \\(void\|double\|int\\) is looking for void or double or int. If you want to match an actual bracket, you just use (.

Comment: ok, for this grep: `grep -n -e "\(void\|double\|int\) \w*(.*)$"  input.c` it returns all the lines which contain function declarations;how can i grab just the function name? it's the word before the first "(" and after the void/double/int; how do i specify that??  P.S. if i insert the -f option it doesn't work properly

Comment: ah, strange. I normally `cat input.c | grep ...` so I don't really know how -f works. Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: do you know how can I refer to the word before the first bracket?

Comment: the second part of the first line should do that. `| sed 's/^.*\(void\|double\|int\) \(\w*\)(.*$/\2/g'` pipes the output from the grep | into sed, switches the whole line with the function name. the regex is similar to before, but with \\(\w*\\) around the function name \w*. These brackets capture the name, and then the second part of the sed \2 replaces the whole line with the contents of the second capture (i.e. the function name).

Comment: now I got it, it worked perfectly from the start but that -f ruined everything :)  thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this regex

```
(^|[^\w\d])?(functionName(\s)*\()
```

for example to search all `printf` occurrences

```
(^|[^\w\d])?(printf(\s)*\()
```

to use this expression with `grep` you have to use the option `-E`, like this

```
grep -E "(^|[^\w\d])?(printf(\s)*\()" the_file.txt
```

Final note, what miss with this solution is to skip the occurrences in comment bloks.